# Binding variable in Service with variable in Controller

Tags: angularjs, binding

I try to do some databindings between a controller and a service.
I just want my variable userIsConnected, which is into my controller, has to change as soon as the function getUserIsConnected returns an other value.
Maybe I have to add an attribute userIsConnected into my service?

Here the example :

```js
app.service('UserService', function($http){

    var user = null;
    this.getUser = function (){
        return user;
    };
    this.setUser = function (user){
        user = user;
    };
    this.getUserIsConnected = function (){
        if(user)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };

});

app.controller("NavBarCtrl", function($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, UserService) {

    $scope.signInIsDisabled = true;
    $scope.userIsConnected = UserService.getUserIsConnected();

});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this:

```
 $scope.userIsConnected = UserService.getUserIsConnected();
```

...is that `$scope.userIsConnected` becomes whatever `getUserIsConnected()` outputs in the moment the Controller is initialized. If you want it to continue updating, you should try something like this instead:

```
 $scope.userIsConnected = UserService.getUserIsConnected;
```

And then in your view, you would use `{{userIsConnected()}}`.

HOWEVER, from my experience, this sort of watcher is very expensive on rendering. Because when the view is rendered, it will actually run `userIsConnected()` 10 times before finally giving-up (because in AngularJS, the stack overflow limit is capped at 10).

I used that method in my applications when I first started using AngularJS. But now, I have a directive called "myDynamicMenu", and it detects when a route event has fired using `$routeChangeSuccess` (ie. when user changes page from login to dashboard, or from dashboard to logout to home).

At this event, my menu directive will check the user authentication state (logged-in or logged-out), and it will then display the proper menu (ie. the user menu [dashboard, my settings, logout], or the guest menu [login, register]). This method is much faster at rendering.

**Edit:** Example directive:

```
  app.directive('myDynamicMenu', function ($rootScope, UserService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'my-dynamic-menu.html',
      link: function (scope) {    
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', updateMenuWhenRouteChanges);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function updateMenuWhenRouteChanges () {
          scope.isLoggedIn = UserService.getUserIsConnected() ? true : false;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

Your template would be something like:

```
<div id="guest-menu" ng-show="!isLoggedIn">
   I am a logged-out guest!
</div>
<div id="member-menu" ng-show="isLoggedIn">
   I am a logged-in member!
</div>
```

And drop the menu into your layout using `<my-dynamic-menu></my-dynamic-menu>`.

Comment: Have you an exemple of your directive? Thanks